# C++ compile-time predicate to test if a callable object of type F can be called with an argument of type T

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I would like to create a compile-type function that, given any callable object `f` (function, lambda expression, function object, ...) and a type `T`, evaluates to true, if `f` can be called with an argument of type `T`, and false if it cannot.

Example:

```
void f1(int) { ... }
void f2(const std::string&) { ... }

assert( is_callable_with<int>(f1));
assert(!is_callable_with<int>(f2));
```

I'm thinking that a clever use of the SFINAE rule could achieve this. Possibly somehow like this:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
constexpr bool is_callable_with(F&&, typename std::result_of<F(T)>::type* = nullptr) {
  return true;
}

template<typename T, typename F>
constexpr bool is_callable_with(F&&) {
  return false;
}
```

But this doesn't work, because if `F` is callable with `T`, both overloads participate in the overload resolution and there is an ambiguity. I'd like to rewrite it so in the positive case, the first overload would be picked by the overload resolution over the second one. Not sure if I'm even on the right track here though.

Comment: Well you have to make one overload a worse match for the arguments. For example, you can add an ellipsis to the second overload and add a function that selects one of those two overloads by adding an additional argument `nullptr` (calling `is_callable_with<T>(f, nullptr)`).

Comment: I'm the only one who is counting the days to start using Concepts on his C++ projects? :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A variant of [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22882402/2644390), but following the standard SFINAE test pattern. Again a generic trait with arbitrary parameter types `A...`:

```
struct can_call_test
{
    template<typename F, typename... A>
    static decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<A>()...), std::true_type())
    f(int);

    template<typename F, typename... A>
    static std::false_type
    f(...);
};

template<typename F, typename... A>
using can_call = decltype(can_call_test::f<F, A...>(0));
```

Then a `constexpr` function as you requested:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
constexpr bool is_callable_with(F&&) { return can_call<F, T>{}; }
```

Check [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab7bc9deb742bdb9).

This will work with functions, lambda expressions, or function objects with arbitrary number of arguments, but for (pointers to) member functions you'll have to use `std::result_of<F(A...)>`.

---

**UPDATE**

Below, `can_call` has the nice "function signature" syntax of `std::result_of`:

```
template<typename F, typename... A>
struct can_call : decltype(can_call_test::f<F, A...>(0)) { };

template<typename F, typename... A>
struct can_call <F(A...)> : can_call <F, A...> { };
```

to be used like this

```
template<typename... A, typename F>
constexpr can_call<F, A...>
is_callable_with(F&&) { return can_call<F(A...)>{}; }
```

where I've also made `is_callable_with` variadic (I can't see why it should be limited to one argument) and returning the same type as `can_call` instead of `bool` (thanks Yakk).

Again, [live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47ccc148df2237fd).

Comment: Why return `bool` when you can return `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`?  As written given a non-`constexpr` function pointer, is the return value a compile time constant?

Comment: @Yakk Sure, that's better. I only wanted to keep the same signature as the code of the question.

Comment: Sweet, this works! Couple of nice tricks I didn't know about. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I would make a type trait first:

```
template<class X = void>
struct holder
{
    typedef void type;
};

template<class F, class T, class X = void>
struct is_callable_with_trait
: std::false_type
{};

template<class F, class T>
struct is_callable_with_trait<F, T, typename holder<
    decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T>()))
>::type>
: std::true_type
{};
```

And then if you want, you can turn it into a function:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
constexpr bool is_callable_with(F&&) 
{
    return is_callable_with_trait<F&&, T>::value;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo, the 2nd `false_type` should be `true_type`

Comment: I typically call `holder` `type_sink`, as in it is a place types flow into and do not come out of.

Answer (score 5):

```
template<class F, class T, class = void>
struct is_callable_with_impl : std::false_type {};

template<class F, class T>
struct is_callable_with_impl<F,T,
     typename std::conditional< 
              true,
              void,
              decltype( std::declval<F>() (std::declval<T>()) ) >::type
      > : std::true_type {};

template<class T, class F>
constexpr bool is_callable_with(F &&) 
{ 
     return is_callable_with_impl< F, T >::value; 
}
```

It is basically the same solution as the one posted by `Paul`, I just prefer to use `conditional<true, void, decltype( ... ) >` instead of an `holder` class to avoid namespace pollution.

Comment: Then why not use `decltype( std::declval<F>() (std::declval<T>()), void() )`?

Answer (score 0):

In C++ 17 is now [std::is_invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable):

```
static_assert( std::is_invocable_v<decltype(f1), int> );
static_assert( !std::is_invocable_v<decltype(f2), int> );
```

Took me a while to find, could save some time for someone.