# Initializing class with a lambda passed into constructor, C++11

Tags: c++11, constructor, std-function

Lets consider following example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Caller {
 public:
  Caller(function<void()> callback) {
    callback();
  }
};

main() {
#if defined(ONELINER)
  Caller caller = [] { cout << "test"; };
#else
  function<void()> fun = [] { cout << "test"; };
  Caller caller(fun);
#endif  // defined(ONELINER)
}
```

If we simply try to compile it (with -std=c++11 flag) it will happily finish, and display `test` when run. However if we define `ONELINER` macro compilation will fail with:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:17:40: error: conversion from 'main()::<lambda()>' to non-scalar type 'Caller' requested
   Caller caller = [] { cout << "test"; };
```

I understand that this is caused by the fact that there is implicit conversion from lambda to `std::function` and then implicit conversion from `std::function` to `Caller`, and we cannot perform 2 conversions at the same time.

Is it somehow possible to make syntax `Class object = lambda;` work? I'm asking because I played recently with writing my own small testing framework for educational reasons and I thought that this:

```
UNIT_TEST(test_name) {
  // test content
};
```

is much more elegant than

```
UNIT_TEST_BEGIN(test_name)
  // unit test
UNIT_TEST_END()
```

The former can be achieved with lambdas passed into the `UnitTest` constructor. But with problem that I described I had to use dirty workaround like:

```
#define UNIT_TEST(test_name) \
    ::std::function<void(::Helper*)> test_name_helper; \
    ::UnitTest test_name ## _test = \
        test_name_helper = \
        [&] (::Helper* helper)
```

and it doesn't look elegant at all. But even if this can be done without lambdas I'm still intrigued whether `Class object = lamda;` syntax can be achieved.

Comment: Most standard functions with a callable argument use *templates*.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? `std::function` is a template after all so I guess you have some specific use case in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the constructor as such:

```
template<typename CB>
Caller(CB callback) {
  callback();
}
```

That will allow it to accept *any* callable argument, be it a lambda, a `std::function`, function pointer or functor.

Unfortunately the constructor will also accept any *other* type as well, but give a compiler error when `callback` can't be "called" like a function.

Comment: Brilliant! It's so simple I feel like a fool now.

Comment: On a side note: quick search showed that the accepting-everything problem can be addressed as well with right static assertions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882170/c-compile-time-predicate-to-test-if-a-callable-object-of-type-f-can-be-called).

Comment: TBH if `callback` is used in the initializer list to initialize a `std::function< >`, you'll get a reasonable error straight away. You don't need an additional static assertion for that.