# C++ Compile-time check that an overloaded function can be called with a certain type of argument

Tags: c++

Consider an overloaded function

```
void f(int);
void f(long);
void f(double);
void f(MyClass);
```

And a method in a template class with unknown argument type

```
template <class T>
struct C {
  void method(T arg) { ... }
};
```

I want to check at compile time if there is a version of `f` which can take `arg` as an argument.

```
template <class T>
struct C {
  void method(T arg) { 
    if constexpr (CAN_BE_CALLED(f, arg)) {
      f(arg);
    } else {
      g();
    }
  }
};
```

Is it possible to do that? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882170/c-compile-time-predicate-to-test-if-a-callable-object-of-type-f-can-be-called) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590890/how-to-check-at-compile-time-if-a-function-that-can-be-called-with-a-specific-se) but compiler complained about *unresolved overloaded function type*.

Comment: At the very least, that `if` will need to be a `constexpr if`. If `f(arg);` is illformed, the compiler would complain of it's presence even if the branch could never be taken. Using `constexpr if` fixes that.

Comment: Is it possible to add a function  f() that takes any type and that calls g(). The compiler would do the work for you. I'm not sure how to do this. May be void f(...){g();} ?

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw `template<class T> void f(T&&) { g(); }` sounds like what you are suggesting. But then it gets tricky when you call with `int&` or other almost-but-not-quite-the-same arguments.

Comment: @Mat: `is_invocable` is a little problematic to call with overloads...

Comment: If you struggle create your own test as a templated function  and populate the specialisations. Default template returns false. Available types return true. Then I think you could also add false positives if you want them to be false. You would have to keep it in sync yourself and getting all false positive may be an issues. But it looks like automatic ways are difficult too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [detection idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) to build such a test

```
template<typename = void, typename... Args>
struct test : std::false_type {};

template<typename... Args>
struct test<std::void_t<decltype(f(std::declval<Args>()...))>, Args...>
    : std::true_type {};

template<typename... Args>
inline constexpr bool test_v = test<void, Args...>::value;
```

And use it as

```
template <class T>
struct C
{
    void method(T arg)
    { 
        if constexpr (test_v<T>)
            f(arg);
        else
            g();
    }
};
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/rHS2m8)

Or alternatively

```
template<typename... Args>
using test_t = decltype(f(std::declval<Args>()...));

template<typename... Args>
inline constexpr auto test_v = std::experimental::is_detected_v<test_t, Args...>;
```

Comment: Possibly [std::experimental::is_detected](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Comment: @Jarod42 I was thinking about it, but am unsure how widely available/accepted it is.

Comment: It doesn't work with overloaded functions in GCC =\. But it works if write these templates *after* function declarations, which is rarely acceptable. But in MSVC or without overloaded functions works well.

Answer (score 4):

You might do the following with SFINAE:

```
template <class T, typename Enabler = void>
struct C {
    void method(T arg) {
        g();
    }
};

template <class T>
struct C<T, std::void_t<decltype(f(std::declval<T>()))>> {
    void method(T arg) { 
        f(arg);
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e32ddfaa3b15f96)