# Detect if function with given signature exists

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I'm trying to use template metaprogramming to find a function (not class method) with a specific signature. And to achieve that, I want to use the [detection idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Let's say that I have functions `foo()` and `bar()`:

```
void foo(int x);

template<typename... Ts>
void bar(Ts&& ...args);
```

And another function called `foobar()` that receives a function and a parameter pack. `foobar()` checks if the received function can be called with the parameters received through the parameter pack:

```
template<typename F, typename... Ts>
void foobar(F&& fun, Ts&& ...args) {
    if constexpr(func_with_signature_exists_v<fun(declval<Args>()...)>)
        do_something;
    }
```

I would expect the following results from the `if` statement in `foobar()`:

```
if constexpr(func_with_signature_exists_v<foo(int)>) // true
if constexpr(func_with_signature_exists_v<foo(float)>) // false
if constexpr(func_with_signature_exists_v<foo(int, int)>) // false
if constexpr(func_with_signature_exists_v<bar(int)>) // true
if constexpr(func_with_signature_exists_v<bar(int, int)>) // true
if constexpr(func_with_signature_exists_v<bar(int, float, int)>) // true
```

I tried to follow the steps from the accepted answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404763/c-compile-time-check-that-an-overloaded-function-can-be-called-with-a-certain) link, but the is_detected idiom didn't complain when I tried passing a `float` to a function expecting an `int`.

Also, I'd prefer if I could pass any function to the using statement, instead of explicitly specializing it for one specific function, like here:

```
template<typename... Args>
using test_t = decltype(f(std::declval<Args>()...));
```

Is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for? Or anything similar to it?

Note that this is for a side project, so I'm trying to use C++17, not C++14 or C++11.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable

Comment: "is_detected idiom didn't complain when I tried passing a float to a function expecting an int" you can pass a float to a function expecting an int.  Try it; `foo(3.14f)`.  If foo's signature was `foo( exactly<int> x )`, where `exactly` blocked all conversions, your detected code would work.  But, as written, you got the answer to the question you asked...

Comment: `foobar(bar, 1, 2.4, 3)` -- `bar` is not an object (or value), it is the name of an overload set.  You cannot pass overload sets as function parameters.  There are workarounds, but they don't involve directly passing `bar`.

Comment: Ok, maybe I wasn't clear enough about my intentions. I'm trying to determine if the function accepts the exact types passed to it without casting

Comment: Also, I didn't intend to use it this way: ```foobar(bar, 1, 2.4, 3)```, I would expect more something like this: ```foobar_v<bar, 1, 2.4, 3>```. That was more of an example with which I wanted to show my intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo()` and `bar()` give completely different problems.

First of all: `bar()`, that is a template function.

Given that you want that `bar()` is a template function (different if is a template `operator()` of a `class`/`struct`), if you want something as

```
static_assert(foobar(bar, 1));
```

the best i can imagine, is that `foobar()` should bee a C-style macro; and a variadic one, to make the things more complicated (but don't ask to me to develop that macro).

This is because you can't pass a **template** function as function argument because a template function isn't an object but a set of objects.

For `foo()`, if I understand correctly, the problem is that the detection idiom say true when an argument is convertible to the function argument

```
static_assert(foobar(foo, 3.4)); // you get true but you want false
```

and that you want to pass the function as an argument.

This is simple to solve (but I don't think is very useful).

If you declare (no definition needed) a couple of overloaded functions as follows

```
template <typename ... Args, typename R>
std::true_type fwse (R(*)(Args...), int);

template <typename ..., typename T>
std::false_type fwse (T, long);
```

and a `constexpr` variadic template variable

```
template <typename T, typename ... Args>
constexpr auto func_with_signature_exists_v
   = decltype(fwse<Args...>(std::declval<T>(), 0))::value;
```

you can also write `foobar()` as follows

```
template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto foobar (F, Ts const & ...)
 {
   if constexpr ( func_with_signature_exists_v<F, Ts...> )
      return std::true_type{};
   else
      return std::false_type{};
 }
```

and you get

```
static_assert( foobar(foo, 7) == true );
static_assert( foobar(foo, 3.4) == false );
static_assert( foobar(foo, 1, 2) == false );
```

I don't think is very useful because this works when the types for the `foo()` arguments has to be plain types (no `const`, no references).

If you can avoid to pass values to `foobar()`, and if is OK to pass the `Args...` types directly

```
static_assert( foobar<int>(foo) == true );
static_assert( foobar<double>(foo) == false );
static_assert( foobar<int, int>(foo) == false );
```

you can rewrite `foobar()` as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts, typename F>
constexpr auto foobar (F)
 {
   if constexpr ( func_with_signature_exists_v<F, Ts...> )
      return std::true_type{};
   else
      return std::false_type{};
 }
```

and become more flexible (because can accept also `const` and/or reference types for `Ts...`).

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>

void foo(int x)
 { }

template <typename ... Args, typename R>
std::true_type fwse (R(*)(Args...), int);

template <typename ..., typename T>
std::false_type fwse (T, long);

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
constexpr auto func_with_signature_exists_v
   = decltype(fwse<Args...>(std::declval<T>(), 0))::value;

template <typename ... Ts, typename F>
constexpr auto foobar (F)
 {
   if constexpr ( func_with_signature_exists_v<F, Ts...> )
      return std::true_type{};
   else
      return std::false_type{};
 }

int main ()
 {
   static_assert( foobar<int>(foo) == true );
   static_assert( foobar<double>(foo) == false );
   static_assert( foobar<int, int>(foo) == false );
 }
```

Comment: Looking back at my code, I see that I made a mistake. I don't want to statically assert foobar. Let me change it quickly, and come back to this answer

Comment: @Maki - yes, I see... but I don't see a great difference. Anyway... I don't think that `func_with_signature_exists_v<foo(int)>` it's possible / make sense. Maybe `func_with_signature_exists_v<decltype(foo), int>` that is, almost, what I've made in my answer.

Comment: Alright, I've removed the static assert. I hope that my intentions are clearer now.

Looking at your working example, in the static_assert, what if I don't know the number of parameters and their types? What if I have a variadic template? Would this make any sense?


```template<typename... Ts>
void fun(Ts&& args) {
    static_assert(foobar<std::declval<Ts>()...>(foo) == false);
}```

Comment: @Maki - no, doesn't make sense for a template function; variadic or not. You **can't** pass a template function as function argument.